# How do I delete Stackoverflow Cookies and certificates in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, powershell, google-chrome, cookies, command-line

How do I delete Stackoverflow Cookies and certificates in Google Chrome? I am open to using command prompt, or some script to expire all cookies in commandline.

- Want to only delete specific stackoverflow items, not everything

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is off-topic here and should be asked at SuperUser instead. Please have a look at the 'What questions can I ask here?' page. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open inspector mode (Shift + Ctrl + i) or right click > inspector mode
2. Go to Application Tab
3. Choose "Clear Storage" option

this will clear cookies, storage, service worker and cache.

Comment: looking specifically for stackoverflow items, is there a filter I can apply?

Comment: You can delete one by one, by entering on menu of cookies, local storage, indexed db... But there's not a filter or search.

Comment: Oh, this option will delete only for Stack Overflow.